# MVC3 - RedirectToAction from Edit page back to Details page with parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a master detail scenario going from a list of categories to ingredients.

In the Edit ActionResult I have:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid){
    dc.Entry(mainingredient).State = EntityState.Modified;
    dc.SaveChanges();
    int ID = ?????
    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = ID});
}
...
```

I am basically trying to go back to the page I came from.
For example... from /Ingredient/Edit/2 back to Ingredient/Details/2

**To make this question clearer:**
how do I pass an id from the edit get to edit httppost controller so that I can redirect the user back to the details page again passing the id after they make an update?

Comment: What is the question? `return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = ID});` is in MVC style :)

Comment: @Samich I forgot to mention this is on the HttpPost of controller.  I simply do not know how to get the id from the Edit "get" controller to the "post".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could pass a `url` query string parameter to the Edit action when invoking it. This way you will be able to redirect to:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string returnUrl)
{
    ...
    return Redirect(url);
}
```

or if you already know the controller and action:

```
return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = ID });
```

will be sufficient. The ID you want to redirect back could be passed as action argument.

Comment: thank you.  I have edited my question because what I do not know is how to go from the Edit httppost back to the details page.  Some viewbag to grab the id?

Comment: @Par6, if you have the id in the GET action you could simply set it as a property of the view model that's being sent to the view and inside this view use a hidden field t render the value. Then when the form is submitted to the POST action the id will be posted back and you will be able to retrieve it.